# Spark Streaming: Different average values returned by PairDStream.print

Tags: java, apache-spark, floating-point, spark-streaming, precision

I wrote a spark program for receiving data from `textSocketStream` and I'm calculating the average of a temperature value. When I stop sending data to my Spark cluster after `~1 min`, the average should not change for the time of the window, which is `1h`, so there are about `59 min` over, where nothing should change!

Now to the problem I found: For me, that data amount is right: 100 entries in the windowed `DStream`, but the calculated sum of the values (and so also the calculated average by making `avg = sum / count`) are fluctuating between a few different average values.

Here the console output snippet (after stopped sending data for `windowedTempJoinPairDStream.print()` (sum & count) and `windowedTempAvg.print()` (average), each as `PairDStream<deviceId, [value]>`:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801338000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,(49.159008,100))

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801338000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801339000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,(49.159016,100))

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801339000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159014)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801340000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,(49.159008,100))

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801340000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801341000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,(49.159008,100))

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801341000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801342000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,(49.159008,100))

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801342000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801343000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,(49.159008,100))

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801343000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801344000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,(49.15901,100))

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1472801344000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.4915901)
```

Here the different average values from above, in short:

```
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159014)
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)
(1-2-a-b-c,0.49159008)
(1-2-a-b-c,0.4915901)
```

For me, this seems to be a rounding problem, since  my temperature values are of type `Float`. If this could be possible, how to solve the problem?

**With temperature values of type `Integer` everything worked fine, no fluctuating...**

If useful, here the appropriate code snippet of the program:

```
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> ingoingStream = streamingContext.socketTextStream(serverIp, 11833);

        // 2. Map the DStream<String> to a DStream<SensorData> by deserializing JSON objects
        JavaDStream<SensorData> sensorDStream = ingoingStream.map(new Function<String, SensorData>() {
            public SensorData call(String json) throws Exception {
                ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
                return (SensorData)om.readValue(json, SensorData.class);
            }
        }).cache();


        /************************************************ MOVIING AVERAGE OF TEMPERATURE *******************************************************************/

        // Collect the data to a window of time (this is the time period for average calculation, older data is removed from stream!)
        JavaDStream<SensorData> windowMovingAverageSensorDataTemp = sensorDStream.window(windowSizeMovingAverageTemperature);

        windowMovingAverageSensorDataTemp.print();

        // Map this SensorData stream to a new PairDStream, with key = deviceId (so we can make calculations by grouping by the id)
        // .cache the Stream, because we re-use it more than 1 time!
        JavaPairDStream<String, SensorData> windowMovingAverageSensorDataTempPairDStream = windowMovingAverageSensorDataTemp.mapToPair(new PairFunction<SensorData, String, SensorData>() {
            public Tuple2<String, SensorData> call(SensorData data) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2<String, SensorData>(data.getIdSensor(), data);
            }
        }).cache();

        // a) Map the PairDStream from above to a new PairDStream of form <deviceID, temperature>
        // b) Sum up the values to the total sum, grouped also by key (= device id)
        // => combined these two transactions, could also be called separately (like above)
        JavaPairDStream<String, Float> windowMovingAverageSensorDataTempPairDStreamSum = windowMovingAverageSensorDataTempPairDStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,SensorData>, String, Float>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Float> call(Tuple2<String, SensorData> sensorDataPair) throws Exception {
                String key = sensorDataPair._1();
                Float value = sensorDataPair._2().getValTemp();
                return new Tuple2<String, Float>(key, value);
            }
        }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Float, Float, Float>() {
            public Float call(Float sumA, Float sumB) throws Exception {
                return sumA + sumB;
            }
        });

        // a) Map the PairDStream from above to a new PairDStream of form <deviceID, 1L> to prepare the counting (1 = 1 entry)
        // b) Sum up the values to the total count of entries, grouped by key (= device id)
        // => also combined both calls
        JavaPairDStream<String, Long> windowMovingAverageSensorDataTempPairDStreamCount = windowMovingAverageSensorDataTempPairDStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,SensorData>, String, Long>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Long> call(Tuple2<String, SensorData> sensorDataPair) throws Exception {
                String key = sensorDataPair._1();
                Long value = 1L;
                return new Tuple2<String, Long>(key, value);
            }
        }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Long, Long, Long>() {
            public Long call(Long countA, Long countB) throws Exception {
                return countA + countB;
            }
        });

        // Make a join of the sum and count Streams, so this puts together data with same keys (device id)
        // This results in a new PairDStream of <deviceID, <sumOfTemp, countOfEntries>>
        JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<Float, Long>> windowedTempJoinPairDStream = windowMovingAverageSensorDataTempPairDStreamSum.join(windowMovingAverageSensorDataTempPairDStreamCount).cache();

        // Calculate the average temperature by avg = sumOfTemp / countOfEntries, do this for each key (device id)
        JavaPairDStream<String, Float> windowedTempAvg = windowedTempJoinPairDStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,Tuple2<Float,Long>>, String, Float>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Float> call(Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Float, Long>> joinedData) throws Exception {
                String key = joinedData._1();
                float tempSum = joinedData._2()._1();
                long count = joinedData._2()._2();

                float avg = tempSum / (float)count;
                return new Tuple2<String, Float>(key, avg);
            }
        });

        // print the joined PairDStream from above to check sum & count visually
        windowedTempJoinPairDStream.print();

        // print the final, calculated average values for each device id in form (deviceId, avgTemperature)
        windowedTempAvg.print();

        // ========================================================= START THE STREAM ============================================================

        // Start streaming & listen until stream is closed
        streamingContext.start();
        streamingContext.awaitTermination();
```

**EDIT: Spark App using `StatCounter` for average calculation:**

Just changed my code to work with `StatCounter` for the average calculation, but still getting different average values:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1473077627000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.4779797872435302)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1473077628000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.4779797872435303)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1473077629000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.4779797872435301)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1473077630000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.4779797872435302)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1473077631000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.4779797872435301)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1473077632000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.47797978724353024)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1473077633000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(1-2-a-b-c,0.47797978724353013)
```

Here the new code snippet:

```
/************************************************ MOVIING AVERAGE OF TEMPERATURE *******************************************************************/

JavaDStream<SensorData> windowMovingAverageSensorDataTemp = sensorDStream.window(windowSizeMovingAverageTemperature);

JavaPairDStream<String, SensorData> windowMovingAverageSensorDataTempPairDStream = windowMovingAverageSensorDataTemp.mapToPair(new PairFunction<SensorData, String, SensorData>() {
    public Tuple2<String, SensorData> call(SensorData data) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<String, SensorData>(data.getIdSensor(), data);
    }
}).cache();

JavaPairDStream<String, StatCounter> preparedAvgPairStream = windowMovingAverageSensorDataTempPairDStream.combineByKey(new Function<SensorData, StatCounter>() {
    public StatCounter call(SensorData data) throws Exception {
        return new StatCounter().merge(data.getValTemp());
    }
}, new Function2<StatCounter, SensorData, StatCounter>() {
    public StatCounter call(StatCounter sc, SensorData sensorData) throws Exception {
        return sc.merge(sensorData.getValTemp());
    }
}, new Function2<StatCounter, StatCounter, StatCounter>() {
    public StatCounter call(StatCounter sc1, StatCounter sc2) throws Exception {
        return sc1.merge(sc2);
    }
}, new HashPartitioner(60));

JavaPairDStream<String, Double> avgPairStream = preparedAvgPairStream.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,StatCounter>, String, Double>() {
    public Tuple2<String, Double> call(Tuple2<String, StatCounter> statCounterByKey) throws Exception {
        String key = statCounterByKey._1();
        double value = statCounterByKey._2().mean();
        return new Tuple2<String, Double> (key, value);
    }
});

avgPairStream.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

At least at the first glance this is not particularly strange. As you already suggested this is most likely due to rounding errors. Since FP arithmetics is neither [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) nor commutative and Spark shuffles are nondeterministic we can expect that the results will fluctuate from run to run.

How much you can do about highly depends on your constraints:

- For starters computing average directly is not numerically stable. It is better to use `o.a.s.util.StatCounter` which implements a variant of [the Online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) which has much better numerical properties.
- If you can afford that you can use arbitrary precision numbers like `BigDecimal`.
- Finally enforcing summation order with a little bit of repartition and secondary sort magic can provide consistent (although not necessary precise) results.

Comment: Thank you, then my guess was right... Is it possible that the `StatCounter` caclulates all-time statistics? As I just want to calculate the average for the windowed data this would be a wrong way... What about rounding my values e.g. two positions after decimal point?

Comment: Stat counter can be used in any context, it is not specific to streaming or RDDs.

Comment: I changed my code to use StatCounter, see edit of my question above. But I still get different values back.